# Table fill with JavaScript from variable

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have this table and the ids are eg.: r0c1 = row 0 column 1
I want to populate with this script, but something went wrong (not doing anything):

```js
var data = new Array();
var data[0] = new Array("999", "220", "440", "840", "1 300", "1 580", "2 050", "2 860", "4 800");
var data[1] = new Array("009", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999");

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    document.getElementById("r" + i + "c" + j).innerHTML = data[i][j];
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="r0c0" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r0c1" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r0c2" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r0c3" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r0c4" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r0c5" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r0c6" width=60px></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="r1c0" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r1c1" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r1c2" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r1c3" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r1c4" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r1c5" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r1c6" width=60px></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1) You dont have to use 'var' in front of `data[0]` and `data[1]`, since they become content inside the array, not a variable. You would only need to use a var if you wanted to push to the array instead.

2) i and j were global, don't forget var for them. (var i and var j inside the loops)

3) If you use this technique, you have to make sure that your html contains as many cells as their are elements inside the array. Your arrays contain 9 elements, but there's only 6 cells in each html row, so your script stopped working iocne it tried to find the 7th cell of the first row.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        .gone {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table> 
      <tr> 
        <td id="r0c0" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r0c1" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r0c2" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r0c3" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r0c4" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r0c5" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r0c6" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r0c7" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r0c8" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r0c9" width=60px></td>
      </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td id="r1c0" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r1c1" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r1c2" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r1c3" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r1c4" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r1c5" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r1c6" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r1c7" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r1c8" width=60px></td>
        <td id="r1c9" width=60px></td>
      </tr> 
    </table>
<script>
var data = new Array();
data[0] = new Array("999" , "220" , "440" , "840" , "1 300" , "1 580" , "2 050" , "2 860" , "4 800");
data[1] = new Array("009" , "999" , "999" , "999" , "999" , "999" , "999" , "999" , "999");

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        document.getElementById("r" + i + "c" + j).innerHTML = data[i][j];
    }
}   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sidenote: Using new Array() to create an array is not needed, better would be to use [] or just write out the array completely.

```
var data = [];
data[0] = ["999" , "220" , "440" , "840" , "1 300" , "1 580" , "2 050" , "2 860" , "4 800"];
data[1] = ["009" , "999" , "999" , "999" , "999" , "999" , "999" , "999" , "999"];
```

Or even better:

```
var data = [
    ["999" , "220" , "440" , "840" , "1 300" , "1 580" , "2 050" , "2 860" , "4 800"],
    ["009" , "999" , "999" , "999" , "999" , "999" , "999" , "999" , "999"]
];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and your advices!

Answer (score 0):

Remove variable definition `var` of `data[0]` and `data[1]`. Error came because you have redefined variable `data`

```js
var data = new Array();
data[0] = new Array("999", "220", "440", "840", "1 300", "1 580", "2 050", "2 860", "4 800");
data[1] = new Array("009", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999");

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    document.getElementById("r" + i + "c" + j).innerHTML = data[i][j];
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="r0c0" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r0c1" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r0c2" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r0c3" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r0c4" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r0c5" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r0c6" width=60px></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="r1c0" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r1c1" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r1c2" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r1c3" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r1c4" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r1c5" width=60px></td>
    <td id="r1c6" width=60px></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```